# Where is the reference to the currently used icon theme stored?

Tags: python, themes, icons, pygtk, pyqt

There are several related questions, but I found none that really answered this detail:

**Where is the reference to  the current icon theme stored?**

Since the icon theme can be changed, hence so too the path to its folder, it must be stored somewhere. I'm making an application and I want it to draw its own icons from the icon theme currently in use. I've seen [answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52430/how-can-i-find-the-location-of-an-icon-of-a-launcher-in-use) showing how to retrieve the path using Python and Gtk, but I am using PyQt and would like to avoid importing Gtk as well.

Is there a configuration file somewhere holding the current icon theme's name or path? Or do you know a PyQt means to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A reference to the current icon theme can be found in `gconf-editor` at:

`desktop` > `gnome` > `interface` > `icon_theme`

[image]

You can alternatively read directly `~/.gconf/desktop/gnome/interface$ cat %gconf.xml` file.

Unfortunately, this does not provide a path to the relevant icon theme. I'll check how this setting relates to the path and i'll let you know ;-)

Comment: Yes it's interesting. Especially in your case---Faenza Darkest---which in and of itself is incomplete and takes most of its icons from the main Faenza theme.

Comment: My case is not the best example, cause i've installed gnome3 and my system is currently mixed with gconf and dconf settings...but anyways..

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [PyXDG](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pyxdg) (package `python-xdg` in Ubuntu).  `xdg.IconTheme.getIconPath(iconname)` gets you the path to the give icon.

Comment: This doesn't give me the icon of the current theme. If I take the result of `IconTheme.getIconPath('anki')`, it returns `/usr/share/pixmaps/anki.xpm` which is incorrect since the current theme is 'Faenza' and the corresponding file for Anki is at `~/.icons/Faenza/Apps/`. The Anki desktop file does not specify this pixmaps path either.

Comment: assuming you got the icon theme name you could use: `foo1 = xdg.IconTheme.getIconPath(full_executable_name, size=None, theme='THEME-NAME', extensions=['png', 'svg', 'xpm'])` But i dont know how to query the icon-theme name in the first place ;)

Answer (score 2):

This looks too easy, so I'm probably missing something here... but what about:

```
icon = QIcon.fromTheme("firefox")
```

QT is supposed to take care of this itself.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, [According to the doc](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qicon.html#fromTheme), it should work :) I'll try that.